# post array list in js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to do a post of the following checklist that is an array list
"checklist":["Lugar","Presupuesto","Dia"]

My problem is that i don't know how i can do it. This is my js

```
function crearTodo(nuevoTodo){
    var url = API_URL;
    var todo = JSON.stringify(nuevoTodo);


    $("#button_to_create").click(function(e){
    $("#create_result").text('');
    e.preventDefault();
    var nuevoTodo ;
    if($('#id_to_create').val() == "" || $('#summary_to_create').val()==""){
        $('<div class="alert alert-info">Debes rellenar los campos ID y summary</div>').appendTo($("#create_result"));
    }else if (isNaN($('#id_to_create').val())){
        $('<div class="alert alert-info">La ID del nuevo TODO debe ser numerica </div>').appendTo($("#create_result"));
    }else{
        nuevoTodo = {
            "id" : $("#id_to_create").val(),
            "description" : $("#description_to_create").val(),
            "summary" : $("#summary_to_create").val(),
            "checklist" : $("#checklist_to_create").val(),
            "date" : $("#date_to_create").val()
        }
        crearTodo(nuevoTodo);
    }
});

$("#create_result").text('');


    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type : 'POST',
        crossDomain :true,
        dataType : 'json',
        data : todo,
        statusCode: {
            404: function() {$('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <strong>Oh!</strong> Page not found </div>').appendTo($("#create_result"));}
        }
    }).done(function(data, status, jqxhr) {
        $("#summary_to_create").val();
        $("#id_to_create").val();
        $("#description_to_create").val();
        $("#checklist_to_create").val();
        $("#date_to_create").val();
        $('<div class="alert alert-success"> <strong>Ok!</strong> Todo creado</div>').appendTo($("#create_result"));                 
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function() {
        $('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <strong>Oh!</strong> Error </div>').appendTo($("#create_result"));
    });}
```

and my html that i don't know how to introduce this array

```
 <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Crear un nuevo TODO</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">ID</span> <input
                    type="text" class="form-control" id="id_to_create">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">Descripcion</span> <input
                    type="text" class="form-control" id="description_to_create">
                </div>

                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">summary</span> <textarea
                    type="text" class="form-control" id="summary_to_create"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">checklist</span> <textarea
                    type="text" class="form-control" id="checklist_to_create"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">date</span> <textarea
                    type="text" class="form-control" id="date_to_create"></textarea>
                </div>
                <span id="create_result"></span>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.col-sm-8 -->
          <div class="col-sm-4">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="button_to_create">Create TODO</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

thanks

Comment: What are you POSTing to?

Comment: I posting something like this
     { "checklist":["Lugar","Presupuesto","Dia"],
      "description":"hacer una comida final de curso",
      "id":"1",
      "summary":"Hablar con Sergio"
    }